# obfuscating a Cython source code

Tags: python, obfuscation

After some research on how I can protect my python source code on similar topics here and other sites, most agree that I should convert my .py file to .pyd using Cython, but the problem is in the space where I'm willing to sell the code (forex trading algorithm), a lot of people make living off decompiling source codes ( with extensive knowledge of Assembly)

I know that when using Cython, first the program is converted to a `c file` then`.pyd` 
is there a way to obfuscate the `c code` first then convert to `.pyd` as an additional layer 
and what do you think the best solution here?

> I know ANYTHING can be cracked, I'm just trying to find a solution to
>   make things a bit harder for hackers that it's no longer worth their
>   time!

Answer (score 2):

If there's serious money at stake, obfuscation definitely won't be good enough. Run the code as a service on your own server instead, and sell access to that, so that people who would want to steal it don't even have access to the binary at all.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to give them the code to get executed on their trading terminal!

Comment: @mr.m then your business model is flawed. You cannot protect a muffin recipe from being copied if the people you sell it to need to make the muffins, even if you make it difficult to read. For instance, I could just resell your code as my own, or reverse engineer it.